# How to disable default <a> behaviour of "href" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have a simple sidebar like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <ul class="nav">
      <li class="Page1"><a href="Page1.html">Page1</a></li>
      <li class="Page2"><a href="Page2.html">Page2</a></li>
      <li class="Page3"><a href="Page3.html">Page3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This code exist on each one of the pages: page1.html, page2.html, page3.html.

On Page1.html, I would like Page1 not to be clickable.
On Page2.html, I would like Page2 not to be clickable.
 
On Page3.html, I would like Page3 not to be clickable.

Is that possible to do that without Javascript, i.e. pure HTML & CSS ?
If not, what would be the easiest method to do that using Javascript, jQuery ?

Comment: If PHP is an option, this should not be much of a problem.

Comment: Are you creating dynamic pages with server-side scripting?

Comment: The right approach would be to just make the current page look like it's not clickable, by using CSS. Because you are repeating the html in every page, you just need to add another class to indicate the current page, and write a CSS for that. Makes sense? Almost every web-site does it this way.

Comment: Disabling a link with CSS or Javascript is not really a good approach, as it fails to take into account accessibility issues. See number 10 in the list on this page: [The Ten Most Violated Homepage Design Guidelines](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20031110.html). If you can add a CSS class which changes the style, why not just remove the `<a>` tag? If you can add an `onclick` event with Javascript, why not just remove the `<a>` tag? If you are creating the page dynamically with a server-side language, don't put the `<a>` tag there in the first place. If it's not a link, don't make it a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add

```
onclick="return false"
```

on the `<a>` tag that you want to disable.

Comment: True, but this doesn't describe how to automate this process (getting JavaScript to determine the correct link to disable, then disabling it automatically).

Answer (score 5):

*I'd actually recommend PHP for this, as it avoids possible usability/accessibility problems.*

*Another note: I wouldn't bother doing this anyway. On my website, I keep all links available - the title tells the user where she is anyway, so disabling links only creates trouble.*

No, you need JavaScript, but you don't need jQuery.

Firstly, select the elements:

```
navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
```

You need to convert the `NodeList` into an `Array`. Use this function:

```
function array(a) {
  var r = []; for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    r.push(a[i]);
  return r;
}

navlinks = array(navlinks);
```

Then... call `forEach` and check for the right link, disabling it:

```
navlinks.forEach(function(node) {
  if (node.href == location)
    node.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it *purely* with HTML and CSS, you have to generate a customized sidebar for each page.

However, if you dont mind using PHP, that shouldnt be much of a problem.

Comment: Correct. If text shouldn't be a link, then it shouldn't be in an <a> tag

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be on the server side. In pseudocode that would look something like this

```
links = [
  "Page1" : "page1.html"
  "Page2" : "page2.html"
  "Page3" : "page3.html"
]

html = ""

for linkTitle, linkUrl of links

  if current_url is linkUrl
    html += "<li>#{linkTitle}</li>"
  else
    html += "<li><a href='#{linkUrl}'>#{linkTitle}</a></li>"

return "<ul>" + html + "</ul>"
```