# Disable default behavior of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a list of menus:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#about" id="about">ՄԵՐ ՄԱՍԻՆ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#products" id="products" >ԱՐՏԱԴՐԱՆՔ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#farm" id="farm" >ՏՆՏԵՍՈՒԹՅՈՒՆ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gallery" id="gallery" >ՆԿԱՐՆԵՐ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts" id="contacts">ՀԵՏԱԴԱՐՁ ԿԱՊ</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I use the [address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin to have back/forward along ajax, but I have a little bug that I'm not able to fix.

When I click on the menu, if the page has scrolling, it moves the page until the menu appears in the top of page, but I don't need it do that.

Is there a method to disable this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable default <a> behaviour of "href" attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174445/how-to-disable-default-a-behaviour-of-href-attribute)

Answer (score 11):

Create or modify the `click()` handlers for the links to use the `preventDefault()` method.

For example:

```
$("a").click 
(
    function (evt)
    {
        //YOUR CODE HERE

        evt.preventDefault(); 
        return false;  
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 8):

try adding the following to your links:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Since you are probably adding an event handler to this link for the click event. Just add the return false to the end of it rather than directly on the HTML tag.

Comment: it doesn;t work by so:( `addres` plugin start not working too

Comment: Ok I looked at the plugin sample page and I notice that they are not binding the click event but rather then change and externalChange event. Are you doing the same thing?

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/#

Changed to remove code since it looks like terrible.

Answer (score 1):

'href="#about"' refers to the element with the id 'about'. that is why the page is moved

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="datosResultado">
        1<br />
        2<br />
        3<br />
        4<br />
        5<br />
        6<br />
        7<br />
        8<br />
        9<br />
        10<br />
    </div>
    <ul id="yourMenu">
        <li><a href="#about" id="about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#products" id="products">products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#farm" id="farm">farm</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery" id="gallery">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacts" id="contacts">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="you-click"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $("#yourMenu>li>a").bind("click", function(ev){

        ev.stopPropagation();

        //...your code...

        $("#you-click").html($(this).html());

        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. I just need to set them other `ID` - s, then the `href` value. `<a href="#about" id="_about">`, it is all;)...

Answer (score -3):

As andres descalzo says, it moove becouse they have the same id, then in href. So i just need to change the id of `a` tags

```
    <a href="#about" id="_about">ՄԵՐ ՄԱՍԻՆ</a>
    <a href="#products" id="_products"> ԱՐՏԱԴՐԱՆՔ</a>
   ....................................................
```

it solves the whole problem.

Thanks all of you for your attention, and ideas;)